# How to find which column was sorted and in what order in angular ui.grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-select

How to find which column was sorted and in what order in angular ui.grid. Actually I want to set server based pagination. For this, I what to send data in params as {pageNumber, pageSize, column, order}. Now how to find which column (Name / Age / Number) user has sorted and in what order (ASC / DESC) in angular ui.grid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular ui-grid launches a sortChanged event when a column has been sorted.
You also must explicitly set `useExternalSorting` to true.

You can catch this event in gridOptions in the `onRegisterApi` function and handle sort logic in the callback function that takes the grid and the array of sorted columns as parameters like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    useExternalSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
       ...
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, function(grid, sortColumns){

          // sortColumns is an array containing just the column sorted in the grid
          var name = sortColumns[0].name; // the name of the first column sorted
          var direction = sortColumns[0].sort.direction // the direction of the first column sorted: "desc" or "asc"

          // Your logic to do the server sorting
      });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by pushing a div into the cell header as :-

```
$scope.gridOptions = {

        enableSorting: true,
        enablePaginationControls: false,
        paginationPageSize: 25,

        columnDefs: [

          { field: 'name' },
          { field: 'gender',
              headerCellTemplate : "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents has-sort'>"
                + "<a ng-click='grid.appScope.testFunction(\"gender\")'>Gender <i class='fa fa-sort' ></i></a>"
                +"</div>"
          },
          { field: 'company' }
        ],

        data : [
            {
                "name": "Ethel Price",
                "gender": "female",
                "company": "Enersol"
            },
            {
                "name": "Claudine Neal",
                "gender": "female",
                "company": "Sealoud"
            },
            {
                "name": "Beryl Rice",
                "gender": "female",
                "company": "Velity"
            },
            {
                "name": "Wilder Gonzales",
                "gender": "male",
                "company": "Geekko"
            },
            {
                "name": "Georgina Schultz",
                "gender": "female",
                "company": "Suretech"
            },
            {
                "name": "Carroll Buchanan",
                "gender": "male",
                "company": "Ecosys"
            }
        ]
      };

$scope.testFunction = function(columnName) {
    console.log("Sorting..."+columnName);
}
```

So the  headerCellTemplate will push the div into HTML as :-

```
<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents has-sort'>
   <a ng-click='grid.appScope.testFunction('gender')'> Gender <i class='fa fa-sort'></i></a>
</div>
```

and further you can toggle the order of column in your controller.

**Note:** You need to add grid.appScope to get the scope of current controller.